# Center, or otherwise format, unicode symbol in NSString w/Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, unicode

**DISCLAIMER**: The information in the picture is completely fake and is for testing purposes.

I have a unicode character that I am using in `titleForHeaderInSection` prepended on to an NSString. Some mock text would look like this:

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\U0001F512 %@", fullTitle]
```

Problem is, it's not centered with the rest of the text:
[image]

Is there a way to nudge that padlock up?

Comment: you could give it its own label and nudge the frame

Comment: Have you tried it with an attributed string? This is common issue with regular strings and Unicode characters.

Comment: @MattS. I thought about an attributed string, but not sure what would help here looking through the docs. And danh I would like to avoid that if at all possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately I can say with 99.9% certainty having tried this in the past that it won't work with standard strings, sadly. The way I wound up solving it was using constraints and getting the top and bottom alignment matching between the two labels. I would not recommend messing with frames because it'll only break on rotation (assuming you support it).

Attributed strings *may* fix it but like you found in the docs, probably not because attributed strings seem to only apply centering on text.

The upside to using the constraint approach is it makes it far easier to internationalize your strings later - can't tell you how much trouble I had with translators mangling the Unicode characters.